# How to get a json metadata object with Heroku log drain

Tags: json, heroku, logging, metadata

Right now I'm fetching logs from the backend using Heroku log drains. The problem with that approach is that the logs are streamed line by line and is not possible to get a json metadata object.

What options do I have available to solve my issues? Thank you!

Comment: Did you found the solution? I found some thing here https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.1/pages/sending_data.html, but its not working

Comment: Nope. Don't have a solution yet.